# Storing $_POST values in an array to save them to text file

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple `$_POST` values which I want to store in an array to save to a text file. How would I go about doing this?

PHP code:

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["name"] 
$email=$_POST["email"] 
$msg=$_POST["msg"] 
$origin=$_POST["origin"] 

$file="test.txt"; 
$open=fopen($file,"a"); 

if($open){         
    fwrite($open, $entry); 
        fclose($open); 
}

?>
```

`$entry` is supposed to be the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$data["name"]=$_POST["name"] 
$data["email"]=$_POST["email"] 
$data["msg"]=$_POST["msg"] 
$data["origin"]=$_POST["origin"] 

file_put_contents("filename.txt", serialize($data));
```

and to bring those values back from a file:

```
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents("filename.txt"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// To save
file_put_contents("file.txt", serialize($_POST));

// To get
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents("file.txt"));
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php