# Php input data ontop of txt file

Tags: php, file

I want to Add new data at the starting of my text file. Dats is coming dynamically.

Below is the **code i have try so far :**

```
if(isset($_POST["posten"])){
    $naam = $_POST['naam']."ø";
    $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam']."ø";
    $email = $_POST['email']."ø";
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht']."\n";
    $infile = fopen("berichten.txt","a");
    if (flock($infile,LOCK_EX)){            
        fwrite($infile, $naam);
        fwrite($infile, $achternaam);
        fwrite($infile, $email);
        fwrite($infile, $bericht);
        flock($infile,LOCK_UN);
    }       
    fclose($infile);
}
```

Comment: POST has always the same structure? Or you just want to log incoming POST? Am I assuming right that you want to add new data in begining of file without even touching rest of the file?

Comment: i need the most recent data on top of the file

Comment: I guess you can use most rated answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760525/need-to-write-at-beginning-of-file-with-php with LOCK_EX flag for file_put_contents.

And if you want to log whole POST no matter what it's structure is, just use $dataToWrite = implode("ø", $_POST)."\n";

Comment: Also if you're planning to parse stored data back to php, maybe better way would be to serialize your data - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487595/storing-post-values-in-an-array-to-save-them-to-text-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
if(isset($_POST["posten"])){
$naam = $_POST['naam']."ø";
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam']."ø";
$email = $_POST['email']."ø";
$bericht = $_POST['bericht']."\n";
$file_data = "$naam"."$achternaam"."$email"."$bericht";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('berichten.txt');
file_put_contents('berichten.txt', $file_data);
}
```

Comment: does anyone have a clue?